# WSO2 API Manager not applying changes to external jar files in repository/components/lib

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've implemented a billing engine library based on [monetization interface](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/api/model/Monetization.java) and copied it to repository/components/lib folder. And done all the configurations related to monetization base on [Monetizing an API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-monetization/monetizing-an-api/). Now whenever I change the code in this library and build and copy the new jar file to this folder, it doesn't get applied. I also restart the server every time I make a change. Is there any mechanisms for caching the library files or some other reasons that I overlooked?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors during the startup? Is your code working in the very first place (besides the changes)? Or, is it not picking the JAR at all even from the first deployment? Ultimately, once you add the JAR to the `lib` directory and creates an OSGi bundle and places it inside the `dropins` directory. At each and every startup, the `lib` will be converted to `OSGi`. So, if you have changed the package names or the artifact names, better remove the bundle JAR from `dropins` directory and restart the server.

Comment: Yes, I've had changed the package name, and removing related jar files from `dropins` directory solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR artifacts are converted to `OSGi` bundles during the startup of the servers. If you place any JAR artifacts in the `/components/lib` directory, they will be converted as `OSGi` bundles by WSO2 and added to the `/components/dropins` directory.

If you have changed the package names of the JAR, or the artifact names, you have to remove the existing `OSGi` bundle from the `/components/dropins` directory. Once removed, place the new JAR inside the `/components/lib` directory and restart the servers to load the packages again.